# View the actual configuration of a remote printer

Tags: printing, macos

Someone in the office set up printing from a Mac to a printer connected through USB to a Windows computer (the only Windows computer in the office).  He can't remember how he set it up and no one else can get a configuration to work.

Viewing the print queue settings or options doesn't tell us much.

How can we see the detailed configuration?

Please note, this question is not about getting the printer to work, it is **only** about reviewing the details of an already configured remote printer so that it can be identically set up on another Mac.

The working computer is running OS 10.8.4.  We want to export to 10.8 and 10.7

Answer (score 1):

Lets see if this works for you:

Using the one Computer that successfully made the connection to the printer to find out the printers information.

How to Set or Change Default Print Settings on Mac OS X, using **CUPS** interface which is an Apple’s printing system.

```
http://localhost:631/printers
```

You might get an Message saying the access is blocked (that is normal setting).

Open Terminal and copy paste following:

`sudo cupsctl WebInterface=yes`

Enter the password (system password)

Open the Link now and you will be presented with the printers administration screen.

Comment: That provides some information, but not enough to copy it over to another system.

Comment: That is all there it is, do not know what else you are looking for.